# Is the concept of a "self cleaning" banknote plausible?

Tags: polymers

Although in 2020 there is a big movement of bankers marketers to lean the public towards cashless society, cash in the form of banknotes is still used in many if not most countries.

Cash banknotes can be very dirty in some occasions, especially old banknotes in humid countries and furthermore in humid storage areas.

Is the concept of a "self cleaning" banknote plausible?

Comment: No,  but there are currency launderers.

Comment: Something like idrophobic and self cleaning paints and coatings might be a possibility, like TiOx nanoparticles.